# How would I filter out this column to display only english characters? Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, special-characters, where-clause

[image]

For the table above, how would I filter the column description so that it only shows English characters? (removes out the '`????`s' and the French characters etc)

I know it goes in the where clause, just can't figure out how.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: use collation against the column

Comment: The bigger question possibly is whether you _want_ to filter off those other characters.  If you are using the wrong collation, some of your legitimate data could be appearing as `??????`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot, but I couldn't find anything in your case.

But, if your column doesn't hold more than one `Question Mark(?)` consecutively, this will helps you:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(Name VARCHAR(16))
INSERT INTO @A VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @A VALUES ('தமிழ்')

SELECT *
FROM @A 
WHERE name not like '%??%'
```

**Output:**

```
Name
A
```

If you found any other solutions, mention my name in the comment. That will helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NOT LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable
WHERE  Description NOT LIKE '%[^a-Z]%'
```